# numpy is already installed in my laptop,but python gives error while i'm importing numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, windows-10

I am facing the following error:

```
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\saikr\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\saikr\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 22, in <module>
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_dir,
AttributeError: module 'glob' has no attribute 'glob'
```

this error is occurred in IDE

C:\Users\saikr>numpy

```
'numpy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

this error occurred in cmd

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Are you using a venv?

Comment: sorry to say I don't know what is venv

Comment: virtualenv. PyCharm seems to use it.

Comment: @SaikrishnaRachuri A virtual environment, quite likely that your IDE creates a new one for each project, which IDE are you using?

Comment: Yup, the docs is here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ . Check if there's a folder in your project that you don't know where it's from (maybe hidden), inside you get something like `lib` `include` `bin` `etc`, etc.

Comment: Because `numpy` is not a command, you cannot run it in the command line.

Comment: numpy is not a command so it wont work on cmd. Can u share output of  command => pip list  , use that in pycharm's terminal, where (venv) is written.

Comment: @Gambitier C:\Users\saikr>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
cycler                 0.10.0
Django                 3.0.1
Flask                  1.1.1
glob3                  0.0.1
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
matplotlib             3.1.2
mysql-connector-python 8.0.18
numpy                  1.18.0
pandas                 0.25.3
pip                    19.3.1
pyparsing              2.4.5
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2019.3
setuptools             41.2.0
sqlparse               0.3.0
Werkzeug               0.16.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this::
Type 
`python` in cmd 
then type 
`import numpy as np`

Comment: yes after doing as you said, it's working but I in IDE, I am not able to import it

Comment: check interpreter setting in IDE, if you are using venv then you can install it in it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely your IDE creates a [Virtual Env](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) for each new project you start (linked to pep 405 for more details about venv).
You can use `pip freeze` from your IDE in order to see all installed packages in your current environment

The second error occurs because you are calling a python command from cmd. You need to call `python` command before your code in order to run python commands from cmd

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\saikr>pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.3
Click==7.0
cycler==0.10.0
Django==3.0.1
Flask==1.1.1
glob3==0.0.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
kiwisolver==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
numpy==1.18.0
pandas==0.25.3
pyparsing==2.4.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Werkzeug==0.16.0

C:\Users\saikr>